# Save return value from python-Luigi

Tags: python, scheduling

Here is a simple example of what I have. If I have two tasks step1 and step2, and step1 is a dependency, how can I read the return value (from output) of step1 in step2?

```
class step1(luigi.Task):

    shardNum = luigi.Parameter()

    def run(self):
        with open('workfile1', 'w') as f:
            f.write("TEST")

    def output(self):
        return [luigi.LocalTarget("workfile1")]
        #HOW DO I READ THE RETURN VALUE OF THIS IN STEP2?

class step2(luigi.Task):

    def requires(self):
        #HOW CAN I GET THE TARGET; luigi.LocalTarget("workfile1"); AND USE IT ELSEHOW?
        return step1()

    def run(self):
        with open('workfile2', 'w') as f:
            f.write("TEST")

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("workfile2")
```

EDIT: This seems to be hackish, but working (is there a better/cleaner way?)

```
class step2(luigi.Task):

    ...

    def run(self):
        print(self.requires().output()[0])#prints the output from last function
        with open('workfile2', 'w') as f:
            f.write("TEST")

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the concise way to do it:

```
class step2(luigi.Task):
    ...
    def run(self):
        with self.input()[0].open() as f:
            f.write('TEST')
    ...
```

It would be cleaner if you did not wrap the output target from task1 in an array, then you could just directly do `with self.input().open()...` to get the data.